# Is there a way to decrease value in one result row if criteria has been met in another result row within a same query

Tags: mysql

I have a table (in real life it is a complex query that gives me this result). Each row represents supplier's different deadline commitment:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| supplier | days_left | prod_type | prods_to_deliver | prods_in_transit |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |    20     |     1     |         9        |         7        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |    20     |     2     |         5        |         3        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |     5     |   NULL    |         7        |         4        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |    20     |   NULL    |         9        |         6        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Tricky part is that per every supplier there can be max two rows with **prod_type = NULL** each having different **days_left** values. And for **prods_in_transit** the highest row always includes values of lowest row as well which I have to correct.

Let's mark highest **days_left** value row with **(H)** and lowest value row with **(L)**.

I am looking for a SELECT that would alter my result in a following way:
If there are both **(H)** and **(L)** rows present then for the **(H)** row **prods_in_transit(H) = prods_in_transit(H) - prods_in_transit(L)**

Output should then look like this:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| supplier | days_left | prod_type | prods_to_deliver | prods_in_transit |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |    20     |     1     |         9        |         7        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |    20     |     2     |         5        |         3        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |     5     |   NULL    |         7        |         4        |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|      1   |    20     |   NULL    |         9        |       >>2<<      |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for the last row's **prods_in_transit** value should get calculaged **6-4=2**

This should be one SQL query since it will be run over big amount of different suppliers. My example only illustrates just one fragment. It is also not an option to run through each supplier's result with PHP foreach, since that will take a lot of time.

Ideally I would have given you some code i have in mind already, but really, i have no idea where to start with this.

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (SUPPLIERID INT, PRODS_TYPE INT, days_left int, PRODS_IN_TRANSIT INT);
INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1,1,1,2),(1,2,2,7),(1,NULL,5,4),(1,NULL,20,6),
(2,1,4,1),(2,NULL,7,10),
(3,1,6,3)
; 

SELECT SUPPLIERID,PRODS_TYPE,days_left,PRODS_IN_TRANSIT FROM T WHERE PRODS_TYPE IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT SUPPLIERID,PRODS_TYPE,days_left,prods_in_transit 
        FROM T 
        WHERE PRODS_TYPE IS NULL 
        and prods_in_transit = 
        (select min(prods_in_transit) from t t1 where t1.supplierid = t.supplierid and t1.prods_type is null)
UNION ALL
(
select t.supplierid,t.prods_type,t.days_left,p
from t join
(
SELECT SUPPLIERID,PRODS_TYPE,max(prods_in_transit) maxint,MAX(PRODS_IN_TRANSIT) - MIN(PRODS_IN_TRANSIT) P 
        FROM T
        WHERE PRODS_TYPE IS NULL 
        GROUP BY SUPPLIERID,PRODS_TYPE HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
) t1 on t1.SUPPLIERID = t.SUPPLIERID and t1.maxint = t.prods_in_transit
) 

ORDER BY SUPPLIERID;


+------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
| SUPPLIERID | PRODS_TYPE | days_left | PRODS_IN_TRANSIT |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
|          1 |          1 |         1 |                2 |
|          1 |          2 |         2 |                7 |
|          1 |       NULL |         5 |                4 |
|          1 |       NULL |        20 |                2 |
|          2 |          1 |         4 |                1 |
|          2 |       NULL |         7 |               10 |
|          3 |          1 |         6 |                3 |
+------------+------------+-----------+------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works. Though i see that in my situation there's a lot of computation for mysql in case of big data.

Comment: If I was you I would leave the question open for a while and see if anyone else chips in